# Is there an alternative to escaping '/' in vi editor when searching for strings with '/' in them?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, grep, vi

I frequently find myself searching for paths such as `/a/b/c/file.txt` in files (log files, scripts, etc.), using vi editor. This is usually on some server machine, to which I connect using SSH, so I'm looking for solutions which don't require a GUI editor.

It's painful to have to escape all those `/`s every time I want to search for string such as a file path.

Is there any alternative to using `/` while searching in `vi`? Or, is there some setting that will allow me to set this search character to something else? (even if it sets it only for the active session)

I know I can use `grep`, but a solution in `vi` would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `?` character instead of `/`, But the only difference is `/`will do a forward search from top to bottom where as `?` will search from last to first line.

Comment: Wasn't aware of backward search in vi...this worked...I just had to reverse 'n' and 'N' to go to the next/previous match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another delimiter, such as `#`:

```
:s#search#replace#g
```

#### Test

Given a file with this content:

```
hello this is me/you
```

I type:

```
:s#me/you#otherthing#g
```

And now the text is:

```
hello this is otherthing
```

Comment: That's substitution, not just searching.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `:cmap <C-/> \/`